# cakePHP value for empty option

Tags: php, cakephp, formhelper, cakephp-2.4

is there a way to pass a value for the empty option in a select dropdown generated by the FormHelper?

I'm creating an input like this:

`echo $this->Form->input('supplier_id', array('empty'=>true));`

with values supplied automatically from the controller like this

```
$suppliers = $this->Product->Supplier->find('list');
$this->set(compact('suppliers'));
```

and the select box is created like this:

```
<select name="data[Product][supplier_id]" class="form-control" id="ProductSupplierId">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Lolë Montreal</option>
  <option value="2">Spiritual Gangster</option>
  <option value="3">Havaianas</option>
</select>
```

but I would like the first option (the empty one) to have a value of 0 instead of '' is it possible? or should I instead modify the `$suppliers` array in the controller with something like

```
$suppliers[0] = '';
```

and remove the empty option from the FormHelper input?

Comment: so why not just type in **0** ?

Comment: @Dagon Where would I type it?

Comment: Pass it for the value of the `empty` option, ie instead of `true`. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs

Comment: @ndm Sorry maybe I wasn't clear.. I would like the value of the option to be 0.. the label can either be blank or something like -choose one-

Comment: Ah ok, I'll add an example as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the verbose array syntax you can chose any value for empty:

```
echo $this->Form->input('supplier_id', ['empty' => ['0' => '']]);
```

See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $this->Form->input('supplier_id', array('empty'=>'Select'));
```

You can also add **required** to it:

```
echo $this->Form->input('supplier_id', array('empty'=>'Select', 'required' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3.x you will get troubles with this...

It will be like

```
Select
0
   value1
   value2
   value3
   ...
```

So I fixed it by:

- In controller:

  ...something to get data from database

  $data_init = ['0'=>'Select'];

  $data = $data_init + $query->toArray();

  $this->set( '$list', $data);
- In view:

  'options' => $list,

And the list will be like:

```
Select
value1
value2
value3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above will work but, if you want to `validate` field through `model` then you need to use this

```
  <?= $this->Form->control('supplier_id', ['options' => $suppliers, 'empty' => '--Select--']) ?>
```